# How to increase the Sessions Limit in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I see in my HAProxy Statistics Report that

the Sessions Curr, Max, Limit all at 2000.

How do I increase the Max and Limit to more than 2000?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `maxconn`

> Sets the maximum per-process number of concurrent connections to <**number**>

Source: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#maxconn

Comment: concurrent connections <> session though. a session can be alive with no connection.

Answer (score 3):

It's the `maxconn` option, but not in the global section as @Ton Hong Tat mentions.

> **maxconn**  
>   Fix the maximum number of concurrent connections on a frontend

Documentation for frontend max sessions: 
https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/snapshot/configuration.html#4-maxconn

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase maxconn.

edit haproxy with your favorite editor
under frontend http,  add following
  **maxconn 4000**

example as below

**frontend localnodes**

```
bind *:8080

mode http

default_backend nodes
```

> **maxconn 4000**